# Random permutation of each cell in a cell array

Tags: matlab, random, permutation, cell-array

I have a *1*-by-*4* cell array, `D`. Each of the cell elements contains *2*-by-*2* double matrices. I want to do random permutation over each matrix independently which in result I will have the same size cell array as `D` but its matrices' elements will be permuted and then the inverse in order to obtain the original `D` again.

for a single matrix case I have the code and it works well as follows:

```
A=rand(3,3)
p=randperm(numel(A));
A(:)=A(p)
[p1,ind]=sort(p);
A(:)=A(ind)
```

but it doesn't work for a cell array.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Look at using `cellfun` or a `for`-loop, `randperm` and the second output of `sort`. Post the code of your attempt and describe exactly where you are stuck

Comment: for a single arbitary matrix I have the code and it works well but it doesn't work for a cell array.

Comment: @Dan      %permutation
A=rand(3,3)
p=randperm(numel(A));
A(:)=A(p)
[p1,ind]=sort(p);
A(:)=A(ind)

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian, edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian please edit your question and add the code to the question, it is not easy to read in comments. But also, if it works for a single matrix then why not just write a loop?

Comment: @A.Donda  edited that code.

Comment: @Dan  because i am going to impliment it for big size matrixes and using loops will make it slow.

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian using `cellfun` will likely be slower. Since you've used a cell-array loops might be you only option. But if all you matrices are the same size, then why not just use a 3-D double matrix?

Comment: @Dan  Thanks for your code. Yes my matrices are the same size but I dont know what is 3-D double matrix??

Comment: @HaybertMarkarian let's say your elements of `D` are `A1`, `A2` etc... then instead of constructing `D` as `D={A1,A2}` rather do `D = cat(3,A1,A2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for you is to use a loop:

```
nd = numel(D);
D_permuted{1,nd} = [];
D_ind{1,nd} = [];
for d = 1:nd)
    A=D{d};
    p=randperm(numel(A));
    A(:)=A(p)
    [~,ind]=sort(p);

    D_permuted{d} = A;
    D_ind{d} = ind;
end
```

Assuming your `D` matrix is just a list of identically sized (e.g. *2*-by-*2*) matrices, then you could avoid the loop by using a 3D double matrix instead of the cell-array.

For example if you hade a `D` like this:

```
n = 5;
D = repmat([1,3;2,4],1,1,n)*10  %// Example data
```

Then you can do the permutation like this

```
m = 2*2;  %// Here m is the product of the dimensions of each matrix you want to shuffle
[~,I] = sort(rand(m,n));  %// This is just a trick to get the equivalent of a vectorized form of randperm as unfortunately randperm only accepts scalars
idx = reshape(I,2,2,n);
D_shuffled = D(idx);
```